# How to calculate the number of CPU, memory and storage that my Google Cloud SQL needs

Tags: google-cloud-sql

My DB is reaching the 100% of CPU utilization and  increasing the number of CPU is not working anymore.
What kind of information should I consider to create my Google Cloud SQL? How do you set up the DB configuration?

Info I have:

- For 10-50 minute a day I have 120 request/seconds and the CPU reaches 100% of utilization
- Memory usage is the maximum 2.5GB during this critical period
- Storage usage is currently around 1.3GB

Current configuration:

```
vCPUs: 10   
Memory: 10 GB   
SSD storage: 50 GB
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no magic formula for determining the correct database size. This is because queries have variable load - some are small and simple and take no time at all, others are complex or huge and take lots of resources to complete.

There are generally two strategies to dealing with high load: Reduce your load (use connection pooling, optimize your queries, cache results), or increase the size of your database (add additional CPUs, Storage, or Read replicas).

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when we have CPU utilization, it is because the CPU is overloaded or we have too many database tables in the same instances. Here are some common issues and fixes provided by [Google’s documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/operational-guidelines):

> If CPU utilization is over 98% for 6 hours, your instance is not properly sized for your workload, and it is not covered by the SLA.

> If you have 10,000 or more database tables on a single instance, it could result in the instance becoming unresponsive or unable to perform maintenance operations, and the instance is not covered by the SLA.

When the CPU is overloaded, it is recommended to use this documentation to [view the percentage of available CPU](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/instance-info#usage) your instance is using on the Instance details page in the Google Cloud Console.

It is also recommended to monitor your CPU usage and receive alerts at a specified threshold, set up a [Stackdriver alert](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/alerts).

[Increasing the number of CPUs](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu) for your instance should reduce the strain of your instance. Note that changing CPUs requires an instance restart. If your instance is already at the maximum number of CPUs, shard your database to multiple instances.

Google has this very [interesting documentation](https://cloud.google.com/spanner/docs/introspection/investigate-cpu-utilization) about investigating high utilization and determining whether a system or user task is causing high CPU utilization. You could use it to troubleshoot your instance and find what's causing the high CPU utilization.