# Google cloud SQL - CPU at 100%

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql

Earlier we noticed that our Master DB CPU started spiking:

[image]

There wasn't any unusual traffic volume/load. Also, if you look at the earlier spikes they coincide with the Google backups, but it looks like there wasn't one on the 19th despite it saying that it was run in the operations logs. I'm guessing that the Google backup went wrong on the server and it went out of control the next morning when it eventually ran.

I've cloned that server and moved the traffic across to the new server and now the CPU has dropped to 10-20% but this is still a lot higher than normal (1-5%)

Things that I've checked:
- Process list
- Traffic volumes
- DB/Table sizes

Any ideas how to get to the bottom of what's causing the change? or how to fix?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to calculate the number of CPU, memory and storage that my Google Cloud SQL needs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54298966/how-to-calculate-the-number-of-cpu-memory-and-storage-that-my-google-cloud-sql)

Answer (score 1):

High CPU usage in a database can be caused by a bunch of different things. It might have been a wide or inefficient query, a backup process gone wrong, or a few other likely suspects.

If your app can support downtime, you could try shutting it down and restarting to get a fresh state.

If you have the support package, you can also open a ticket and ask them to look into the spike farther. If you don't, you can still open an issue on the [Cloud SQL issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=187202&template=0), but the response time might not be as fast.

Comment: No, even with a support package the response time is ~1 business day.

Comment: I don't think it's query related since we hadn't significantly increased the data size and/or changed the queries that would be running at that time. Also nothing showing in the slow query logs.

Comment: From 4.50pm, about 9 hours, after the initial start of whatever caused the problem. The server now looks to have gone back to normal...I guess Google stopped whatever they were doing. Let's hope it's resolved.

Comment: A few hours later Google announced they had a problem on SQL: https://status.cloud.google.com/incident/cloud-sql/19002 It looks like it's resolved but CPU numbers are still high

Comment: The response time with the support package is much less than ~1 business day. See https://cloud.google.com/support/ - the max response times vary between 4 hours and 15 minutes depending on tier and circumstances. 

The incident report you linked to seems to be around the Cloud SQL Admin API. I would still suggest restarting the instance or opening an issue on the tracker if the numbers concern you.